# Django ORM join without foreign keys and without raw queries

Tags: django, join, orm

## A

```
class AKeywords(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="kw_id")
    word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"A"."Keywords"'
```

## B

```
class BKeywords(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="kw_id")
    word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"B"."Keywords"'
```

I have another model where i would like to perform my join.

```
class XKeywords(models.Model):
    ...
    k_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"public"."XKeywords"'
```

I have two models that are very similar, one comes from a database schema and another from another database schema.
A third model that will be to join with table A or B has i want.

How can i join model A or B without using foreignkeys and raw queries?

Comment: Do you want to join on `k_id == AKeywords.id` or `k_id == BKeywords.id`?

Comment: Onetime i would like to join A in other time i could join B. i would like to have freedom to choose when i like to join. i expect someting like `kwds= XKeywords.objects.filter(pk_id=3).join(k_id__in = AKeywords_k_id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
XKeywords.objects.filter(pk_id=my_id).extra(select={'word':'SELECT word FROM "A"."Keywords" WHERE "public"."XKeywords".k_id = "A"."Keywords".kw_id'})
```

or

```
raw_sql = """SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "public"."XKeywords" WHERE pk_id = my_id) as "XK" LEFT OUTER JOIN  "A"."Keywords" as "AK" ON "AK".kw_id = "XK".k_id ;"""
XKeywords.objects.raw(raw_sql)
```

This is an workaround i was expecting something more "clever". It would be nice to have something more directly like:

```
XKeywords.objects.filter(pk_id=my_id).join(k_id=A.kwd,from={"AKeywords":"A"})
```

Answer (score 23):

The current way to do this is with a `Subquery` and an `OuterRef`:

Example taken from my code. `Store` and `StoreInformation` have a field called `store_number`.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

Store.objects.annotate(timezone=Subquery(
      StoreInformation.objects.filter(store_number=OuterRef('store_number')).values('store_timezone')[:1]
))
```

This is joining to add a field called `store_timezone`.

Comment: Can someone provide  an example query of what this queryset would look like?