# Join 2 tables with no ForeignKey link

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, foreign-keys, django-orm

I have a SQL query that joins 2 tables and I'm trying to replace it with Django ORM. The query:

```
SELECT * FROM students r JOIN class_teachers c ON c.class_room_id = r.class_room_id
```

Pretty simple. Purpose of it is to get all values from students and the Teachers ID from class_teachers table.

I created 3 models that are using pre built tables in the db:

```
class ClassRoom(models.Model):
    class_room = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class ClassTeachers(models.Model):
    class_room = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teachers)

class Students(models.Model):
    class_room = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

But with this setup I can't figure out how to create a two table join like before. The closest I got was with this which is horrible... but works:

```
dd = ClassTeachers.objects.filter(
        company_id=company_id,
    ).annotate(
        name=F('classroom__classteachers__name'),
        all_student_fields...
    ).values(
        'teacher_id',
        'name',
        all_student_fields...
    )
```

and it creates a 3 table join:

```
SELECT st.*, ct.teacher_id
FROM class_teachers ct INNER JOIN class_room cr ON (ct.class_room_id = cr.class_room_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN students st ON (cr.class_room_id = st.class_room_id)
WHERE ct.class_room_id = '123';
```

Is there a way to create a 2 table join getting the teacher id and all student table fields without the need to join the ClassRoom table?

Comment: Duplicate question, refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291372/django-orm-join-without-foreign-keys-and-without-raw-queries

Comment: So basically the only way to do it is using raw sql?

Comment: Another option is `.join` but not recommended. But you get students objects using RAW