# Retrieve values from the JOIN of two models without foreign key (Django)

Tags: sql, django, join

I want to retrieve the values of two columns related to two different models (without foreign keys). In SQL, I would write it as this:

```sql
SELECT employees.name, companies.name
FROM employees
JOIN companies
ON companies.location=employees.location;
```

Suppose the two models are called `Employee` and `Company`. They have no foreign keys in common, and I am not allowed to change the models.

How can I have the same in Django? Should I necessarily write a raw SQL query?

Comment: Could you filter for location?

Comment: `location` is just a regular column, it's not a Django model in my case.

Comment: Have you looked at this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291372/django-orm-join-without-foreign-keys-and-without-raw-queries

Comment: @BriseBalloches thank you, I was able to use the information in the answer you linked to work on a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I will add the answer as future reference for other users, since the similar question linked in the comments is not very detailed.

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

Employee.objects.annotate(
    company_name=Subquery(
        Company.objects.filter(location=OuterRef('location')).values('name')
    )
).values_list('name', 'company_name')
```

## Explanation

Dividing it into parts (from the inside to the outside):

1.

```
OuterRef('location')
```

This creates a reference to the `location` attribute of the `Employee` objects. It's called **Outer**Ref because it refers to the model that is used outside of the subquery (that calls the subquery).

2.

```py
Subquery(Company.objects.filter(location=OuterRef('location')).values('name'))
```

The subquery returns the names of all the companies whose `location` is the same as the employees'.

3.

```py
Employee.objects.annotate(
    company_name=Subquery(...)
)
```

This is basically annotating the `Employee` objects returned by the "global" query with a new field called `company_name`. This field stores the results of the subquery from (2).

The resulting SQL query would be like this:

```sql
SELECT employees.name,
  (SELECT companies.name
   FROM companies
   WHERE companies.location = employees.location) AS company_name
FROM employees
```

(I simplified some clutter generated by Django ORM).

### Note

It is important to note that this will use **subqueries** (and not **joins**). This might affect performance in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

For such requests, you should write raw SQL...

But are you sure you don't actually need a foreign key here ?

Comment: I can't change the models, so having a foreign key is not an option in my case. Also, I'd like to focus my question on the possibility (or not) to achieve the same results as the SQL query I posted, in my current setup. If Django can't do it without raw SQL queries, I guess that's the answer :)